# Flutter - how to have a widget respond to touch and flick?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Currently in the design phase of an app. One of the goals we have is to be able to touch a certain widget, and on tap and hold, have the widget then follow the user's finger where they drag.

Then, if the user releases gently, the widget snaps back to the original location.

However, if the user flicks the widget, we want the widget to fly across the screen, reacting correctly to the user's flick.

Is there anything built-in that can handle this? Also, if this needs to be explained more to make sense, happy to elaborate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think for such cases you can use `GestureDetector` widget. It provides several useful functions. See here:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

You can use onPanStart of GestureDetector and then get the offset and use it to move the widget accross the screen.